# APEX - select list - how to have selection set multiple page items

Tags: apex

I have an APEX "select list" which is populated by a list of values SQL query.  I'm trying to figure out how to have the select list selection result in more than one page item being set.

I have a single selection select list with a list of values set via a simple sql query.
ex:

page item name: P1_ITEM_ID
type: select list
page action on selection: Redirect and Set Value
list of values:

- type: SQL query
- query:

select item_desc, item_id
from item_table
order by 1;

With this configuration, a selection sets P1_ITEM_ID to the item_table's "item_id" value.  However, assume "item_table" has additional columns, say "item_type" and "item_price", which I'd like to be accessible in session state as text fields (P1_ITEM_TYPE, P1_ITEM_PRICE) upon the select list selection.  Any suggestions as to how I could do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using a **dynamic action**. You can create a dynamic action that fires on the change event of your select list. The true action of the dynamic action can be set to execute PL/SQL code or JavaScript code that sets the values of the other page items based on the selected value of the select list.

For example, you could create a dynamic action with the following properties:

- Event: Change
- Selection Type: Item
- Item(s): P1_ITEM_ID
- Action: Execute PL/SQL Code or Execute JavaScript Code

In the PL/SQL or JavaScript code, you can use the selected value of P1_ITEM_ID to query your item_table for the corresponding item_type and item_price values, and then set the values of P1_ITEM_TYPE and P1_ITEM_PRICE accordingly.

Comment: Creating a dynamic action as you specified worked - thanks!

Comment: Event: Change  
Selection Type: Item  
Item(s): P1_ITEM_ID  

Action: Set Value  
Set Type: SQL Statement  
select item_type  
from from item_table  
where item_id = :P1_ITEM_ID;  

Item to submit: P1_ITEM_ID  
Affected Elements:  
 P1_ITEM_TYPE